# Filter based on value of adjacent cell of GridView/ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, filter

I have a ListView with a variable number of items in a WPF project with two columns. Column A is a string, column B is a combobox. I have the ListView bound to some collectionView, and the combobox column is a cellTemplate, binding the combobox to some other collectionView or observableCollection.

Is there some way to filter the collection shown in the combobox in column B dynamically based on the value of column A?

I am open to replacing the ListView with some other control if it would grant me the functionality described.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could achieve this by binding the combobox property B's ItemsSource to

```
{Binding Path=PropertyA, Converter={StaticResource ItemsConverter}}
```

Then write a IValueConverter which takes a TypeA and returns a IEnumerable. Whack that into the Resources so the StaticResource can find it.

Bob's your uncle.